# nginx ingress controller dropping the response headers/ how to get the response headers from external authentication

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am using nginx ingress controller and external authentication to route to my application via authorize app. Below is my ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://b20bdc2b8916.ngrok.io/authorize
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-method: POST
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hw1.yourdomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes-first
          servicePort: 80
  - host: hw2.yourdomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes-second
          servicePort: 80
~
```

The authorized API return response headers(principal-id, app-type) which I want to get from the below command

```
curl -X GET "http://hw1.yourdomain" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik15dDZzVVd2WWdkS253WHVlVE9XaC0zNVFzdnFRSjk3aDdOTFhVdkt4YUkifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHR*****"




  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   668  100   668    0     0     49      0  0:00:13  0:00:13 --:--:--   152HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Mar 2021 09:35:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 668
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"29c-/QY+HmD5p/HwK1AOeM+b3H5wbI0"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Kubernetes!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300" >
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main">
    <img src="/images/kubernetes.png"/>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="message">
  Hello from the first deployment!
</div>
<div id="info">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>pod:</th>
      <td>hello-kubernetes-first-8477fc565d-gb22w</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>node:</th>
      <td>Linux (4.19.157)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the response header from the auth-url ?

Comment: are you using a custom header ? by default Nginx will drop the header if not following HTTP standard.

Comment: Yes these are custom header. what is the http standard nginx checks

Comment: are you using _ in your headers?

Comment: No I am not using _(underscore) but I am using -(Hypen)

Comment: oh okay. ideally HTTP standard suggests use -(Hyphen) only. Still if you can please try but updating configmap i faced a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the custom header Nginx will drop your deader if not following the HTTP header.

It's mainly possible when you are using the `_` in your headers.

In this case, you can update the Nginx configmap and restart the Nginx PODs to allow and pass the custom headers.

You can open the config map of Nginx and update the configuration.

```
enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
```

Example Nginx config map

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

Comment: I removed the underscore from my headers but still not able to get the response headers. I am not using any special character in the response header now

Comment: the custom response headers which you got from auth-url you are able to see as request headers for backend service?